# identifier "is a method, which is not valid in the given context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

So I have t he following code:

```
public class SampleService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public double FahrenheitToCelsius(double Fahrenheit)
    {
        return ((Fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
    }
}
```

and this for my button click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new WebServiceSample.SampleServiceSoapClient();
    textBox2.Text = client.FahrenheitToCelsius.parseDouble(textBox1.Text);
}
```

What I am trying to do is convert the value placed in `textBox1` (Fahrenheit) and to display it in Celsius in `textBox2`, however my code is giving me this error

> 'WindowsFormsTemp.WebServiceSample.SampleServiceSoapClient.FahrenheitToCelsius(double)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Any Clues?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not calling the web service correctly.
To simplfy put it on multiple lines for you

```
    var client = new WebServiceSample.SampleServiceSoapClient();
    var input = parseDouble(textBox1.Text);
    double result = client.FahrenheitToCelsius(input);
    textBox2.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: parseDouble does not exist in current context :/

Comment: I think he means `double.Parse(textBox1.Text)`